# How to create an array of usersnames when working with Parse and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am trying to create an array of strings for all the usernames using the following code and populate a TableViewController.

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var randomUser = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var query: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            if let objects = (objects as? [PFObject]!){
                for object in objects{
                        self.randomUser.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)
                    print(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)
                    print(self.randomUser.count)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print(self.randomUser.count)
}
```

the output in the console:

```
0
username
1
username
2
username
3
```

But UItableview does not populate.. What could be causing this?
My guess is that query is delayed and view is created before it can return data. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You need to call `self.tableView.reloadData()` after you get the results of the query. Below is an example of where to call it.

```
private var usersArray = [PFUser]()

func fetchUsers() {
    let userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!

    userQuery.orderByAscending("username")
    userQuery.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: (currentUser?.username)!)
    userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (users, error) -> Void in


        if error == nil {

            self.usersArray = users as! [PFUser]
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
```

In this example, you can then access the `username` property by doing `usersArray[i].username`

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! You could have saved me half a day!! :))